# Unable to link backend post api with frontend submit button

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I am trying to make a zomato random restaurant generator, so whenever you put your city it gives a random restaurant in that city. I made api for it and it works perfectly, this is a sample output of the api call

```
{
    "name": "Natural Ice Cream",
    "url": "https://www.zomato.com/ncr/natural-ice-cream-rajouri-garden-new-delhi?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1",
    "location": {
        "address": "J 2/10, BK Dutt Market, Rajouri Garden, New Delhi",
        "locality": "Rajouri Garden",
        "city": "New Delhi",
        "city_id": 1,
        "latitude": "28.6474674597",
        "longitude": "77.1195488423",
        "zipcode": "",
        "country_id": 1,
        "locality_verbose": "Rajouri Garden, New Delhi"
    },
    "price": 1,
    "thumbnail": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/pictures/8/313368/da7c191473cdc9701aa97a8cbcd51255.jpg?fit=around%7C200%3A200&crop=200%3A200%3B%2A%2C%2A",
    "rating": "4.7"
}
```

the backend linking frontend to backend looks like this

```
searchForm.addEventListener('submit', async e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  resultArea.innerHTML = '';
  const query = e.target.querySelector('#restaurant-name').value;
  if (query === '') {
    return
  }
  
  e.target.querySelector('#restaurant-name').value = '';
  const res = await fetch(`${hostname}/locations/${query}`, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    method: 'POST', 
  })
  const json = await res.json();
  populateData(json);
});

function populateData(results) {
  results.forEach(result => {
    const newResult = rTemp.content.cloneNode(true);
    newResult.querySelector('.result-title').innerText = result.name;
    newResult.querySelector('.result-neighborhood').innerText = result.location.locality;
    newResult.querySelector('.result-address').innerText = result.location.address;
    newResult.querySelector('.result-price').innerText = '$'.repeat(result.price);
    newResult.querySelector('.result-thumbnail').src = result.thumbnail;
    newResult.querySelector('.result-website').href = result.url;
    resultArea.appendChild(newResult);
  });
}
```

here `rTemp` is querySelector('template') and `resultArea` is querySelector('#restaurant-results') and `hostname` is this.location.origin

And lastly this is the frontend

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <main>
      <h1>Restaurant <span>Random</span></h1>
      <form action="">
        <div class="form-wrapper">
          <label for="restaurant-name">Search</label>
          <input name="restaurant-name" type="text" id="restaurant-name" placeholder="City Name">
        </div>
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
    </main>
    <hr>
    <section id="restaurant-results">
    </section>
  </div>
  
  <template>
    <div class="result-card">
      <div class="result-header">
        <h2 class="result-title">${title}</h2>
        <h3 class="result-location result-neighborhood">${neighborhood}</h3>
        <h3 class="result-location result-address">${address}</h3>
        <p class="result-price">${price}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="result-body">
        <img src="" alt="restaurant-photo" class="result-thumbnail">
        </div>
      <div class="result-footer">
        <button class="result-footer-button">Call</button>
        <button class="result-footer-button"><a href="" target="_blank" class="result-website">Visit Website</a></button>
        <button class="result-footer-button">Make Reservation</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

When I run this I get the following error

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/locations/delhincr 405 (Method Not Allowed)
(anonymous) @ index.js:16
```

index.js:16 is

```
const res = await fetch(`${hostname}/locations/${query}`, {
```

and

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at HTMLFormElement. (index.js:22) which is

```
const json = await res.json();
```

I am unable to locate the error. How do I solve these?

Comment: Haven't looked to deep into your code. My first guess: You get something back you don't expect. Not a json, instead an HTML page or something like this. Just check the request which the browser sent before getting this error. Check the response body of it.
The first error is for the 405 you get. You have to check your backend for that.

Comment: @Citrullin i checked again in the api call im doing doing res.json() and js file of linking front end with backend im doing   const json = await res.json();

Comment: This is what you meant right?